# text received from a database doesn't overflow to a new line

Tags: html, css, database, text

```html
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            setInterval(function() {
                $("#load_results").load("db_results.php");
            }, 1000);
        });

    </script>

<div id="aline">
        <div id = "load_results"></div>
        
        </div >
```

Hi i have text from a server the text was going off the page so i turned overflow to hidden. What I mean about the text not overflowing is meaning the text isn't going underneath each other when it reached the end of the page how would I make it so the text will continue on underneath were it left off please help.

Comment: Might need some more information, like what tag is it in, how is it styled? A snippet might help. If the container is inside another container that has a specific style setup it could cause the problem also.

Comment: Share the code please?

Comment: @Silas code is posted

Comment: @TarunDugar  code is posted

Comment: it is coming from more code which retrieves the text from a database. the code above is what views it in list form

Comment: do #aline or #load_results have any css?

Comment: @TarunDugar no just plain I've tried max-width and overflow hidden and centre aline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using:

```
#load_results {
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`<div id= aline>`

should be

`<div id= "aline">`